# Create efficiently `DataSetIterator` out of large double[][] array

Tags: deeplearning4j

I have large (1M samples * 100 features) array of type `double[][]` loaded into memory and I need to create efficiently `DataSetIterator` (with random batches) to feed `MultiLayerNetwork`. How can I do that?

Most of the deeplearning4j examples I found focuses on loading data from files, but what to do when the data are already in the memory?

Answer (score 2):

DataSetIterator is just a way of creating mini batches. A minibatch dataset is a data set object which itself is just 2 INDArrays (features and labels)
If your data is already in memory, a simple:

```java
double[][] data = ...;
INDArray arr = Nd4j.create(data);
```

Note when you do this this will move a bunch of data off heap and allocate a ton of extra memory. A big reason why we don't work with normal java data structures is because (while easy to use) due to performance reasons all of our compute happens in c++.

For creating the dataset you would use

```java
DataSet d = new DataSet(arr,arr);
```

Note that the second arr in the constructor actually should be a separate second array representing your dataset.

For the iterator (which just creates these underneath the covers) you could use something like:
https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/blob/master/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-data/deeplearning4j-utility-iterators/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/datasets/iterator/impl/ListDataSetIterator.java

with:

```java
DataSetIterator listIterator = new ViewIterator(data,5);
```

Note the 2nd parameter is your batch size.